# Including usercontrol with same file attribute value causes multiple control error upon post only

Tags: asp.net, exception, user-controls

We have two placeholders, only one is ever visible, visibility is set during pageload.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cecontrols" Namespace="Controls" Assembly="Components" %>
```

Inside each placeholder, is the tag: (notice the ID is different for each, but the File attribute value is the same)

`<cecontrols:Include ID="IE7MessageDisabled" runat="server" File="/IE7-Message.ascx" />`

and

`<cecontrols:Include ID="IE7MessageEnabled" runat="server" File="/IE7-Message.ascx" />`

This works fine, until the user issues a POST to the page, then we get the 500 error:

Why is a POST causing this? How can we fix this?

```
<error host="" type="System.Web.HttpException" message="Multiple controls with the same ID 'IE7-Message' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs." source="ExcptManag" detail="   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.FindControl(String id)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)" time="2013-10-03T06:53:06.437Z" />
```

Comment: What is inside `IE7-Message.ascx`?

Comment: which version of .net framework are you using?

Comment: By the way there is a plenty of same questions at stackoverflow. The problem is that there are several items witht the same uniqueid. You can check that in the html code of the page. Do you generate unique ids manually?

Answer (score 1):

Visibility doesn't influence whether something is on the DOM. If you don't want something to appear in the DOM, use display:none. In this case, the same page is loaded twice, and the controls in that file are added to the DOM twice.